# How to wrap a string value in variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

In my function below I draw the markers with a chosen icon

```
function addMarkers(name) {
   var iconVal = "";
   if(name == 'default'){
    iconVal = defaultIcon;
   }
   else if(name == 'school'){
        iconVal = 'schoolIcon';
   }

   marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { icon: iconVal });
}
```

My question is how can I pass the variable iconVal as above. Is there any function that does that like Html.Raw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use variable names for these things. Use an object with properties that are accessible by name:

```
var icons = {
    default: new L.Icon.Default(),
    school: L.icon({
        iconUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Content/custom/schoolpin.png")',
        iconSize: [32, 50],
        iconAnchor: [16, 50], 
        popupAnchor: [-3, -76] 
    }),
    test: L.icon({
        iconUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Content/custom/testpin.png")',
        iconSize: [32, 50],
        iconAnchor: [16, 50], 
        popupAnchor: [-3, -76] 
    })
};

function addMarkers(name) {
   var iconVal = icons[name];
   var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { icon: iconVal });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the icon's were global variables (and I'm NOT suggesting they should be; just hear me out), you could access the variable like this:

```
   marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), window[icon].iconVal);
```

It's not quite so straightforward to dynamically access local variables, so use iconVal to hold the whole icon object, instead of a "pointer".  This is assuming that `addMarkers` directly has access to the local icon objects.

```
function addMarkers(name) {
  var icon;
  if(name == 'default'){
    icon = defaultIcon;
  }
  else if(name == 'school'){
    icon = schoolIcon;
  }

  marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), icon.iconVal);
}
```

Comment: ... Bergi's answer is a more direct approach.